# Mostrar mensajes de errores en los llamados a las apis cuando el servidor esta caido

Tags: reactjs, axios

Mi consulta esta orientada a cuando hago una llamada a un endpoint del back end y este por decir un ejemplo no esta corriendo. Hasta el momento yo muestro un mensaje en este caso de login incorrecto(cuando el usuario o password son incorrectos), pero tambien en estos casos se muestra ese mensaje, lo cual esta mal(quiero mostrar un mensaje general que tome en cuenta los status code). Como yo puedo manejar esos errores y mostrarlos en la interfaz. Estoy trabajando con react y la libreria axios para hacer las consultas a las apis.

Configuracion de axios

```
import axios from "axios"
const clienteAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://localhost:44328",
})

export default clienteAxios
```

Users Actions

```
 //funcion que realizar el login de un usuario
  const loginUsuario = async (datos) => {
    try {
      const respuesta = await clienteAxios.post("/api/account/login", datos);
      //console.log(respuesta)
      //console.log(respuesta.config.data);
      Swal.fire("Correcto", "El usuario se logueo correctamente", "success");

      //jwt decode
      const decoded = jwt_decode(respuesta.data.token);
      console.log(decoded.unique_name);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_EXITOSO,
        payload: {
          token: respuesta.data.token,
          userActive: decoded.unique_name,
        },
      });

      history.push("/usuarios");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);

      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Login Fallido",
        text: "No se ha podido loguear al usuario",
        //footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
      });

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
        payload: error.response,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Según tengo entendido, si el servidor está en funcionamiento debería enviar un código de error al fallar la petición (ya sea si no se encontró el recurso, o algún otro problema), más el mensaje con la descripción del error, por ejemplo:

`{
 success: false,
 status: "400",
 message: "BAD_REQUEST",
}`

Luego en el catch deberías tener algo similar a esto:

```
catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response);

  Swal.fire({
    icon: "error",
    title: error.status,
    text: error.message,
    //footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
  });

  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_ERROR,
    //acciones
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Simon. saludos